# Text appear as boxes in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating to  Android Studio Arctic Fox arabic text appear as boxes in the IDE , the problem seems to be mac only related as the text works fine on windows ,i tried changing the font but it did nothing to the problem

[image]